# "Can't resolve constructor" when using type alias inside class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, clion

I'm fairly new to C++, so please forgive me if I'm being naive here. I have a snippet that demonstrates my issue:

```
template<typename _T, typename _Key, typename _Val>
class Foo {
    typedef std::pair<_Key, _Val> _P1;
    using _P2 = std::pair<_Key, _Val>;

    _T *t = new _T();
    _P1 *p1 = new _P1();
    _P2 *p2 = new _P2(); // (IDE) error: can't resolve constructor '_P2'
}
```

My understanding is that `using` is equivalent to `typedef`. Why do the first two declarations work but the third one is flagged by my IDE? Furthermore, it compiles without errors and I can obtain `_P2*` pointers just fine. What's going on here?

Comment: [It works for me](https://ideone.com/uuILus) Which IDE are you using? Which version?

Comment: CLion 2016.2.3, with the latest update.

Comment: Identifiers that start with underscore followed by uppercase are reserved to the implementation. It's not a good idea to use them. You're not guaranteed that the code will compile, or that it will have any specific effect if it compiles.

Comment: It's good to be aware, that C++ is fairly complicated to parse, and all IDE's that I've used for C++ inevitably had both false negatives and false positives (the exception is a properly configured libclang setup, but AFAIK CLion does not use libclang for this). So in general, your IDE flagging something, doesn't mean it's wrong. Try compiling it, and if it compiles either your IDE is misconfigured, or it's a bug.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I'll take them on board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's definitely a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-4392) in CLion