# C++11 - vector of tuples

Tags: c++11, tuples, stdvector, unique-ptr

I've created a type

```
using Parameter = std::tuple<unsigned int, std::string>;
```

and in my class, I have a property like this (note: vector, unique_ptr and string are all included - there is no problem)

```
class MyClass
{

public:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Parameter>> parameters;

public:
    explicit MyClass(const std::vector<std::string> &data);
};
```

with definition

```
MyClass::MyClass(const std::vector<std::string> &data){
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i += 2) {
        this->parameters.insert(
            std::unique_ptr<Parameter>(
                static_cast<unsigned int>(std::stoi(data[i])), 
                std::string(data[i + 1])
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Result by a compiler:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::tuple<unsigned int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::insert(semac::command::Parameter)’
```

So my question: Is there such a way to create an instance of `using MyTuple = std::tuple<...>;` as I tried in the code? What is the best way to do this generally?

Comment: You try to insert a `Parameter` *object* into vector of (unique) *pointers* to `Parameter`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah, you're right but I also tried `std::unique_ptr<Parameter>(static_cast<unsigned int>(std::stoi(data[i])), std::string(data[i + 1]))` and similar error occured: no mathinch function for call to ...

Comment: How about plain `parameters.push_back(std::make_unique<Parameter>(static_cast<unsigned int>(std::stoi(data[i])), data[i + 1]));`?

Comment: Or if you don't have `std::make_unique` then `parameters.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Parameter>(new Parameter(static_cast‌​<unsigned int>(std::stoi(data[i])), data[i + 1])))`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Great! That's it but I can't use the `std::make_unique` (i guess it'a C++14 feature, right?). Is there another way than creating the new variable? With `std::move` semantics, it won't make any performance change, right? I just want to know if it is possible... Any way thank you! Edit: you were faster than me, thanks :)

Comment: try `emplace_back`?

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<Parameter>(new Parameter(static_cast‌​<unsigned int>(std::stoi(data[i])), data[i + 1]))` That's essentially what `make_unique` would have done.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ye, that's it. I was also confused because I'm using Clion IDE and there is still this bug - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40564746/cant-resolve-constructor-when-using-type-alias-inside-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(I'm creating the answer just to make this question answered)*

As Igor Tandetnik and Some programmer dude said, the right way to do this is using `std::make_unique` or `std::unique_ptr<Parameter>(new Parameter(static_cast‌​<unsigned int>(std::stoi(data[i])), data[i + 1]))`

The final code could look like this:

```
MyClass::MyClass(const std::vector<std::string> &data){
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i += 2) {
        this->parameters.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Parameter>(new Parameter(static_cast‌​<unsigned int>(std::stoi(data[i])), data[i + 1])));
    }
}
```

As user6386155 metioned, it can be done using the emplace_back method ([std::vector::emplace_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back)).

```
MyClass::MyClass(const std::vector<std::string> &data){
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i += 2) {
        this->parameters.emplace_back(new Parameter(static_cast‌​<unsigned int>(std::stoi(data[i])), data[i + 1]));
    }
}
```

---

Also be careful when using the CLion IDE (2017.2.1), there is a bug

- ["Can't resolve constructor" when using type alias inside class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40564746/cant-resolve-constructor-when-using-type-alias-inside-class)
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-7536

I was very confused because of it.